# Setting active link dynamically on static navigation

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have "navigation.html" (static coded  navigtaion ) file loaded on multiple pages, using jQuery .load()
Now I need to  dynamically set active `<li>` for each page user clicking on. I can not use body id for specific reasons.
Any other ways to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you can identify your current page by class or id (ex: body > div#contacts) for contacts.html and this class/id is unique then you have to match it with you navigation, other way is to match `window.location.href` value (parsed if you want) against your navigation.

`changeActiveLink` is defined in JS (ex:init.js) file which you include to each page

```
function changeActiveLink() {
  var currentLocation = window.location.href;
  currentLocation = currentLocation.replace('//', '/').split('/');
  var page = currentLocation[currentLocation.length - 1];

  if (page == "") { page = 'index.html'; }

  $('#leftNav1 a[href*="'+ page +'"]').addClass('active');
}
```

This line is called from each file when "init.js" is included.

```
$('#leftNav1').load('navigation.html', changeActiveLink);
```

Comment: Is it possible to get example of your idea?

Comment: not working for me, probably because of my navigation.html is a separate page and is being loaded dynamically...

Comment: Do you call $.load() in every single files? if no did you try to use complete callback function on $.load() ?

Comment: Solution 1; add callback function to $.load(); Solution 2: do it manually for each file (which isn't so nice).

Comment: I do not see other way of doing .load(). I have to have it on each page .<script type="text/javascript">
  $("#leftNav1").load("navigation.html, function () {
    $('#leftNav1 a[href*="'+ currentPage +'"]').addClass('active'); ");

</script>And it does not work...

Comment: My previous comment was before edit the post with source code.

Comment: no problem :) if my way works i will appreciate if you mark my answer. regards Ivelin

Comment: on left side of my answer you have arrows up and down, under them there is one check icon which you click and then we all are happy :)

Answer (score 1):

Or you can use any HTML or even HTML5 tag to specify li item.

```
  <li class="some">
```

or

```
  <li title="some">
```

or

```
  <li attr-specify="some-specific-in-url">
```

and jQuery with window.location object
      $('li[title="' + window.location.path + '"]').addClass("active");

Comment: Okay seems legit, but how he will get current page ? `[some]` must be dynamic value specific for every page he has.

Comment: Ok, but question is for **static page navigation**. So you can use javascript window.location to get actuall href

Answer (score 0):

You could set up some jquery script to get the url and then find the href of the li that matches that.  This will allow you to addClass() to that li of active.

This of course will only work if your href matches the url